can't make users loging for spotify api web app in streamlit
I coded and deployed to streamlit a python app that shows spotify stats for the user (top songs, artists, etc) but, whenever I try to login with my account from another device, I get an error message "accounts.spotify.com refused to connect."
github repo: https://github.com/juansuero/wrapped2.0/blob/main/stats.py
this is my auth code
# spotify_auth.py
import os
import streamlit as st
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

DEBUG = True

def log_debug(msg):
    if DEBUG:
        st.write(f"Debug: {msg}")

# Use st.secrets for deployment, fallback to env vars for local dev
try:
    REDIRECT_URI = st.secrets["REDIRECT_URI"]
    CLIENT_ID = st.secrets["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"]
    CLIENT_SECRET = st.secrets["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"]
except:
    REDIRECT_URI = os.getenv('REDIRECT_URI')
    CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID')
    CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET')

if not all([REDIRECT_URI, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET]):
    st.error("Missing credentials in both secrets and environment variables.")
    st.stop()

SCOPE = 'user-top-read user-read-recently-played user-library-read'

def create_spotify_oauth():
    """Create SpotifyOAuth instance for authentication"""
    try:
        # Add debug logging
        log_debug(f"Using production URI: {REDIRECT_URI}")
        
        oauth = SpotifyOAuth(
            client_id=CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI,
            scope=SCOPE,
            cache_path=False,  # Disable local caching
            show_dialog=True,  # Always show auth dialog
            requests_session=True,  # Enable session handling
            open_browser=False  # Don't auto-open browser
        )
        
        return oauth
    except Exception as e:
        log_debug(f"OAuth creation failed: {str(e)}")
        raise

def get_token():
    """Get cached token or create new one"""
    try:
        sp_oauth = create_spotify_oauth()
        token_info = sp_oauth.get_cached_token()
        if DEBUG:
            log_debug(f"Token info retrieved: {'Yes' if token_info else 'No'}")
        if not token_info:
            auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
            log_debug(f"Auth URL generated: {auth_url}")
            return None
        return token_info
    except Exception as e:
        log_debug(f"Token retrieval failed: {str(e)}")
        return None

how do i fix it? it's driving me crazy!!!
I've tried using ai to help me but i still get the same error message
